# Is is possible to create a custom jpa annotation in java

Tags: java, jpa, orm

Jpa one of the big successfull module of jpa and so are its annotation features .I have weird requirement in which i need to create jpa annotation ,one that jpa can process

ex. We have in jpa  a table annotation that create a table for this java pojo class.
i need to make another annotation that behaves exactly as what table annotation does + some of my custom reqirements;

what is mean
if i create a customAnnotation like @Anil that is suppose to work same as @Table Annotation does 
than

@Anil 
public class Anp
{
}
than this should create a table in the database is that possible or not .if it is give me some way to do this 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

JPA does not process just any annotation. The JPA implementation processes the annotations that **it** supports and these are typically just the `javax.persistence` annotations, and optionally its own extensions. Your JPA provider may allow you to define your own, but this is not going to be very common - look at the docs for your JPA provider if they allow a user to define annotations.

For example, the JPA provider I have used (DataNucleus JPA) allows the user to provide annotations for the [class](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/extensions/class_annotation_handler.html) or for the [field/property](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/extensions/member_annotation_handler.html).